# Converting decimal number to binary in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a decimal number to binary but I somehow end up getting 'random' ASCII symbols as an output. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int i = 50;
    char binary[10];
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
     while(number!=0){
         binary[i] = number % 2;
         i--;
         number = number / 2;
    }
    printf("\n%s", binary);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the number enter is `0`, `printf("\n%s", binary);` attempts to print uninitialized memory - amongst other issues (like no terminating null character.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code (no specific order but the one I found them):

- You are initializing a `char` with an `int` at line `binary[i] = number % 2`; you should properly transform the integer to a character, like this:

  ```
  binary[i] = '0' + (number % 2);
  ```
- You are writing `printf("\n%s", binary);` where `binary` is a `char[10]`, thus not necessarily null-terminated. You should add one more character to `binary` and initialize it to `\0`:

  ```
  char binary[11];
  binary[10] = '\0';
  ```
- You are wrongly initializing your array: you start with `i = 50` and `binary[10]`. You should add a constant and use it twice:

  ```
  #define MAX_SIZE 32
  int i = MAX_SIZE - 1;
  char binary[MAX_SIZE + 1];
  binary[MAX_SIZE] = '\0';
  ```

  Note the `-1` you forgot, that avoids that you write after the end of the string, and the `+1` that is essentially the last problem
- You are reading an `int` and trying to get its binary representation; but the (true) binary representation of a negative value is usually not what you would expect. Prefer reading an `unsigned int`:

  ```
  unsigned int number;
  scanf("%u", &number);
  ```
- You could replace `number % 2` with `number & 1` and `number /= 2` with `number >>= 1`; which is more representative of exactly what (binary) operations you are running on `number`. Besides, this should actually work correctly on negative integers, where your version should not (untested, anyway you usually have no reason of wanting to get the binary representation of a negative integer):

  ```
  binary[i--] = '0' + (number & 1);
  number >>= 1;
  ```
- You stop after your number is zero, but that means you did not necessarily fill the `binary` array; this implies you may have uninitialized characters at the beginning of `binary` (on VC++ in debug mode this should IIRC be displayed as `ÿ` characters). You should add, after your loop, something such as this so as to fill the array:

  ```
  while (i >= 0)
      binary[i--] = '0';
  ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If I enter `10` it returns `@`

Comment: Just adding last point to address what may be the first problem you face

Comment: Sorry but I feel the answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Excuse me? Have you at least tried reading all my points and using the proposed resolutions? Even if it does not solve all your problems, it will certainly solve at least 4 reasons that make your program bug **for sure**. That's 4 fewer bugs.

Comment: Besides, I just tested it, the corrected version (with all proposed fixes applied) actually **does** work. And no, I won't post the complete code here so you are forced to understand the "why" of your mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize i to 50 yet your binary buffer is only 10 characters in length.  So you are not populating the correct elements inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 32

int main()
{
    unsigned int number = 0;
    int i = MAX_SIZE - 1;
    char binary[MAX_SIZE + 1];
    binary[MAX_SIZE] = '\0';
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%u", &number);

    while(number!=0)
    {
        binary[i--] = '0' + (number & 1);
        number >>= 1;
    }

    while (i >= 0)
        binary[i--] = '0';
    printf("\n%s", binary);
}
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

You are filling in your array from the back to the front. You stop once the number is "done", and don't "left pad" the remaining characters at the start of the array so they are not initialized. Either initialize the whole array to `'0'` at the start, or add something like:

```
while(i >= 0) {
    binary[i] = '0';
    i--;
}
```

at the end. (I think I'd got with initializing to '0'). You also need to ensure that `buffer` is big enough (50, not 10). And insert chars, not ints: `binary[i] = '0' + (number % 2);`

Comment: Runs into an endless loop.