# Convert decimal number to binary in C

Tags: c, binary

For an assignment I need to convert a 16-bit decimal number to a binary number. So for example the number 9 should print 0000000000001001. My professor started us with this code:

```
void printBinary(short n)
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    short n;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%hd", &n);
    printBinary(n);
}
```

I am very confused as to where to go from here. I really would appreciate anyone helping me understand what to do, as I am very new to coding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand how to convert a decimal to binary? If no, don't start writing code, read some book or google it.

Comment: Read up on bit operators in C. In particular the mask (`&` and `|`) and shift (`>>` and `<<`) operators. Simple examples: `my_int & 0x1` will be 1 if the 0-th bit in `my_int` is set and 0 otherwise. `my_int & (0x1 << 1)` will give the same for the 1-st bit and so on.

Comment: The main thing you'll need to worry about is the user entering  `-9` instead of `+9` (or, in general, negative numbers).

Comment: `short` is not necessarily 16 bits and you should use an unsigned type. use `uint16_t` and appropriate format macros.

Comment: @Olaf: `short` is at least 16 bits. Why should he use an unsigned type when the professor has given a code outline using a signed type?

Comment: @NisseEngström: I overread that this bad code was supplied. As stated, the question askss for using an 16 biot type, not one with **at least 16 bits**. And An unsigned type will have a standard representation and defined shift-behaviour for all values. Not to mention for binary output a sign does not make sense.

Comment: @Rick: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: There are many similar SO posts  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30089264/2410359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int printBinary(int integer)
{
  int remainder, counter = 0, my_binary = 0;
while (integer > 0)
{
    remainder = integer % 2;
    my_binary += remainder * pow(10, counter);
    integer /= 2;
    counter++;
}  

  printf ("Binary is %d\n", my_integer");
}
```

This has been taken from [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/197651-c-decimal-to-binary-converter/).

**NOTE:** I have the assumption that you want to convert only positive decimals.

Comment: Mixing integer and floating point is most times a bad idea; here it is just wrong (and nonsense, too). That is very certainly not what the prof of OP intended. You also have undefined behaviour. That happens if you just copy some code you found on the net.

Comment: This fails for large values of `integer` (and for `integer < -1`).

Comment: @chux, I have already mentioned that this will not work for negative integers. Also, I think that the user is not asking about negative integers and only about positive ones, as he has not mentioned negative numbers. Also, if the number is too big, the binary will also be bigger, and thus the int will not be able to store it. That is why it does not work for too large numbers. You can also make a `long int`, so that it stores more bigger values.

Comment: Code does not even compile.  What is `my_integer"`?  `int printBinary(int integer)` lacks any return value.  Answer does not say "will not work for negative integers".  It does say  "convert only positive decimals", so if code works for negative numbers was left TBD.  My comment parenthetically stated it  does not.  But the largest issue is that it appears to only handle numbers 0 to about 1024 (with 32-bit `int`), far short of OP's 16-bit decimal number.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?