# divison using GMP mpz_cdiv_q never reaches zero

Tags: c++, gmp

I am learning [GMP](https://gmplib.org). So, I decided to write a decimal-to-binary as the first and [the simplest problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089264/converting-decimal-number-to-binary-in-c) or [here](http://programmingknowledgeblog.blogspot.ca/2013/05/c-program-for-converting-decimals-to.html). But, I have got stuck. I do not really understand why my code does not work (The code is dirty, I know):

```
1.   unsigned long int j=0;
2.   unsigned long int idx=0;
3.   unsigned long int p=2;
4.   unsigned long int m=1;
5.   unsigned long int ten=10;
6.   mpz_t decimal,quotient, binary,remainder,multiplicant,base,idx_10;

8.   mpz_inits(decimal,quotient,binary,remainder,multiplicant,base,idx_10,NULL);
9.   mpz_set_ui(base,p);
10.  mpz_set_ui(idx_10,m);

12.  while (mpz_cmp_ui(decimal,j)!=0) {
13.  mpz_mod(remainder,decimal,base); 
14.  mpz_mul(multiplicant,remainder,idx_10); 
15.  mpz_add(binary,binary,multiplicant); 
16.  mpz_cdiv_q(decimal,decimal,base);
17.  mpz_mul_ui(idx_10,idx_10,ten);
18.  }
```

I know that I do not need to define p and m as there are alternative mod and division instructions that accept unsigned integer. But, I though that the problem is because of these. After several hours struggling with the code, I noticed that decimal never become zero which is odd. The decimal never reach zero in '*mpz_cdiv_q*' (line 16) whereas it must become zero. It goes to infinity and decimal never becomes zero as it must. Is it a bug?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A number that has only ones and zeros when written in the decimal system is not a binary number. Binary and decimal are textual representations; an integer by itself does not have a base.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I know. it is exactly why I defined idx_10 to add new digit place every time to make it rather integer than string.

Comment: I'll try and be clearer: "converting", for instance, 4 (*four*) into 100 (*one hundred*) is not a decimal-to-binary conversion. It's "converting" one number into a different number.

Comment: @molbdnilo. OK, but the while loop does this. it iterates until the decimal, which is divided by two, becomes zero. This never happens and the loop continues infinitely. the thing is the algorithm is too simple and as you can see two extremely simple implementation of the algorithms that I mentioned. The thin is why decimal never becomes zero.

Comment: You're not getting the point. Even if you get this working, you're not converting decimal to binary – a different representation of the same  number – you're creating a different number.

Comment: There are 3 types of divisions in GMP, cdiv, fdiv and tdiv, depending on how you want the result rounded. With cdiv, 1/5 gives 1.